# Sequelize Complex Filter | Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i want to filter, but that depend to the user, for example

```
Data.findAll({
    where: {
        name: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { [Op.like]: ['%samsung%'] },
                { [Op.like]: ['%iphone%'] },
                { [Op.like]: ['%alcatel%']}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If the user selects only Samsung, how do I go about filtering only by Samsung?

Comment: How will you get brand name ? In array or comma separated string.

Comment: @HassanImam by req.query

Comment: So I can assume an array then. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `req.query.brands` stores either a single search string or an array of strings we can build `Op.or` conditions on the fly:

```js
const brands = [].concat(req.query.brands)
const brandConditions = brands.map(x => ({
   [Op.like]: `%${x}%`
})
const foundItems = await Data.findAll({
    where: {
        name: {
            [Op.or]: brandConditions
        }
    }
}
```